# Python - class object attribute setter not working

Tags: python

I've got a simple class setup here. What I want to happen is the 'print message' to be printed when I set the attribute '**info**' of the class object **Truck**.

Nothing appears to be happening when I set the info property `c.info = "Great"`
I would expect it to print "this is being set"

```
# Classes
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Truck(Node):
    def __init__(self, name="", age=0):
        super(Truck, self).__init__(name=name, age=age)
        self.info = None

        @property
        def info(self):
            return self.info

        @info.setter
        def info(self):
            print "this is being set"


c = Truck()
c.info = "great"
print c.info
```

Comment: Your @properties are indented too far.

Comment: that doesn't appear to fix it

Comment: Edit the question to fix the indenting so we know not to worry about that any more.

Comment: "nothing appears to be happening"... your code raises a ValueError and that's an interesting bit of information to include in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setter`needs to take a `value`. Furthermore, store the data in `self._info` to avoid recursive calls to `self.info()`.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Truck(Node):
    def __init__(self, name="", age=0):
        super(Truck, self).__init__(name=name, age=age)
        self._info = None

    @property
    def info(self):
        return self._info

    @info.setter
    def info(self, value):
        # you likely want to it here
        self._info = value
        print("this is being set")


c = Truck()
c.info = "great"
print(c.info)
```

This prints:

```
this is being set
great
```